# Mitsubishi Mirage stalling on start, fast idling

Tags: stall, mitsubishi, fast-idle

Mitsubishi Mirage 2017. When I first start the motor, it turns over and starts, but immediately stalls unless I pump the gas to bring the RPM over 1500 for about 20-30 seconds (normal idle RPM is about 900-1100). It then finally will start running relatively smoothly, but idling around 1500 RPM. It drives normally at higher RPM, but if I'm in high gear and it goes below roughly 1500 RPM, it starts to feel feel like it's going to stall out. Occasionally idle will fluctuate between ~1200 and ~1500, spending roughly a second or two at each speed before jumping up/down.

The car was left without starting for about two weeks over the holidays; the check engine light turned on about 10-15 minutes of driving after the symptoms were first noticed, but unfortunately I don't have access to an OBD2 scanner right at the moment.

A vacuum leak seems to match the symptoms, but to date I've been unable to detect one. I know they can be hard to locate; I'm just wondering if anything else could be causing these symptoms which I could rule out or should be considering as a possible diagnostic.

**Update**

Turns out the OBD2 is throwing a `P0016 Crankshaft Position Camshaft Position Correlation Bank 1 Sensor A`. So I was probably way off on my initial train of thought.

Comment: You really need to get the code read. I'll bet that'll point you in the right direction.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 makes sense. I'll let you know when I get my hands on my scanner ;)

Comment: Many auto parts stores will read your codes for free.

Comment: Although reading error codes from Autozone or other stores are free, this may or may not point to the problem especially if the check engine light didn't turn on with starting/high idle problems until recently. Things contributing to mystery problems;  error codes or none, maintenance history, parts replaced, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a major issue; the timing chain was stretched, probably due to inproper maintenance prior to purchase (vehicle was purchased used).

There was also major damage to other engine components, resulting in the best option being an engine replacement.